# BrowserField (v2) on Blackberry V6 devices has no visible pointer

Tags: java, blackberry

We are experiencing a very annoying problem with the BrowserField (v2) in our blackberry java app.

We have a MainScreen subclass that contains nothing but a BrowserField on it. The browser field is set to display the contents of the salesforce.com mobile login page for OAuth. On all devices (OS 5 only) , there is always a pointer to assist in selecting fields and finally clicking on the login button to post the form. On the 9780 and other OS 6 devices this pointer is never visible, no matter how we configure the browserfield.

Is there a known problem with the browserfield and OS6 blackberry devices?

Here is our code:

```
BrowserFieldConfig browserFieldConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();
_browser = new BrowserField(browserFieldConfig);
browserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
add(_browser);
_browser.setVisualState(VISUAL_STATE_FOCUS);
_browser.requestContent(url);
```

Appreciate any help on this. Any known workarounds, hacks etc.

App is compiled against BB JDK 5.0.0.

Comment: I'd have said it was something to do with the Navigation Mode you were using, but it seems you've set it to Pointer ok. If you set it to CARET, do you still struggle to see it?

Comment: Also, try seeing the property of Config object prior to passing it in as a parameter. Might be set within BrowserField in a non-intuitive way.

Answer (score 1):

I faced exactly the same issue,I fixed mine by creating a new object of BrowserFieldConfig,set the properties I want then initialize _browser,like this:

```
BrowserFieldConfig config = new BrowserFieldConfig();
config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.ALLOW_CS_XHR, Boolean.TRUE);
config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
_browser = new BrowserField(config);
add(_browser);
```